# How would I raster a list of binary matrices and find the clumps of 0s?

Tags: r, list, raster, r-package, region

I have included my attempt:

```
set.seed(12345)
x <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

set.seed(9999)
y <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

set.seed(12345)
z <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 225, prob=c(0.8,0.2), replace=TRUE), nrow = 15)

mat_list <- list(x, y, z)

library(igraph)
library(raster)

lapply(list, function (list) {
 Rastermat <- raster(list)
 Clumps <- as.matrix(clump(Rastermat, directions = 8))

 #turning the clumps into a list
 tot <- max(Clumps, na.rm=TRUE)
 res <- vector("list", tot)
 for (i in 1:tot){
   res[i] <- list(which(Clumps == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
 }
})
```

But when I run this I get an output of NULL for each matrix in the list. Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong?

Edited:

```
 lapply(mat_list, function (onemat) {
 Rastermat <- raster(onemat)
 Clumps <- as.matrix(clump(Rastermat, directions = 8))

 #turning the clumps into a list
 tot <- max(Clumps, na.rm=TRUE)
 res <- vector("list", tot)
 for (i in 1:tot){
   res[i] <- list(which(Clumps == i, arr.ind = TRUE))
 }
 res
})
```

Comment: should `lapply(list, function (list) {` be  `lapply(mat_list, function (list) {`? and you should call the argument to your function something other than `list` as well, and you probably need an explicit `return(res)` at the end of your function.

Comment: @Spacedman I have made the edits you specified but now I am getting the error `Error in .local(x, ...) : list has no "x"`? Can you please help?

Comment: You've made too many edits now. I didn't say to change the `Rastermat <-` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are struggling to understand how `lapply` works.

This (from your edit):

```
lapply(mat_list, function (list) {
  Rastermat <- raster(mat_list)
```

applies the function to each element of `mat_list` in turn. Like calling `foo(mat_list[[1]])` then `foo(mat_list[[2]])` etc (where `foo` is like the function you've written in the `lapply`).

Inside the function the element of the list is the argument to the function, which you have named `list` for some reason. This is a bad name for a thing in R because its the name of a function and what the function is getting is an element of the list and not a list itself.

So then you do: `Rastermat <- raster(mat_list)` - which is applying `raster` to *the whole list of rasters* not the single element passed into the function as `list`.

What you want is `Rastermat <- raster(list)` instead. Or better still, define your function as `function(onemat){` and then `Rastermat <- raster(onemat)` to better describe what's going on.

Comment: @Spaceman I have updated the edit in the question and I am now getting a result. Is there a way I could count the number of clumps for each matrix in the list?

Comment: That's a new and very different question - ask it in a new post.